# Check if a directory is a mount point with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a pythonic way and without shell commands (i.e. with subprocess module) to check if a directory is a mount point?

Up to now I use:

```
import os
import subprocess

def is_mount_point(dir_path):
    try:
        check_output([
            'mountpoint',
            path.realpath(dir_name)
        ])
        return True
    except CalledProcessError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an [`os.path.ismount(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.ismount).

> Return True if pathname path is a mount point: a point in a file
>   system where a different file system has been mounted. The function
>   checks whether path‘s parent, path/.., is on a different device than
>   path, or whether path/.. and path point to the same i-node on the same
>   device — this should detect mount points for all Unix and POSIX
>   variants.

```
import os
os.path.ismount(dir_name)  # returns boolean
```

You may also refer to [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/posixpath.py#L180) (if you're on POSIX system). Check `macpath.py` or `ntpath.py` for other platforms.

Comment: I'll also add that you can retrieve all mount points using the [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) library - something like: `mount_points = {el.mountpoint: el for el in psutil.disk_partitions(all=True)}` if you wanted additional information and automatic cross-platform stuff... Then you can use it as `if path in mount_points` as the check or `mount_points[path]` to get the additional info. as a namedtuple...

Answer (score 7):

in Python 3.7, use `Path.is_mount()`

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('/some/mounted/dir/')
>>> p.is_mount()
True
```

Comment: Great answer for modern Python. Note, however, that this method was first added in Python 3.7 (and not in 3.4). Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_mount